# Linq two left outer join Error Non-static method requires a target

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I am unable to execute this error "Non-static method requires a target." and I am not sure why I am having this error.
The below query has four tables in it with one join and two left outer join. it is possible that the last left out join will contain a null row to match

```
var model = from p in Uow.Instance.RepoOf<RoleMenuMetrix>().GetAll()
                    from n in Uow.Instance.RepoOf<NavigationMenu>().GetAll().Where(q => q.Id == p.MenuId)
                    from m in
                        Uow.Instance.RepoOf<NavigationButton>()
                            .GetAll()
                            .Where(q => q.NavigationMenuId == n.Id)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from o in // when I comment this from it works fine, but i donot get the values from this table.
                         Uow.Instance.RepoOf<RoleButtonMatrix>().GetAll().Where(q => q.ButtonId == m.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where p.RoleId == Guid.Parse("96246E99-6BF2-4A3D-8D2C-263DDEF2F97B")
                          && n.IsActive && n.ApplicationName == "MEM"
                    select new
                    {
                        p.MenuId,
                        p.RoleId,
                        n.Name,
                        n.ParentId,
                        ButtonName = m != null ? m.ButtonName : String.Empty,
                        ButtonId = m != null ? m.Id : 0,
                         ischecked = o.RoleId == "96246E99-6BF2-4A3D-8D2C-263DDEF2F97B" ? "true" : "false"//// when I comment this  it works fine, but i do not get the values from this table
                    };
```

Error Screen Shot it generates from the model variable
[image]

below is the Expected output required

[image]

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message, including which part of your code it refers to.

Comment: In future, please include the *text of the error message as text*. It's much, much harder to read a tiny screenshot like that. In this case, just explaining that it's an exception and showing the full stack trace would have helped... although it's entirely possible that this is just a debugger issue. Do you get the exception when trying to actually display the results in your app?

Comment: I cannot do this on my model
"model.Where(q => q.ParentId == null).ToList();" when I comment the lines as mentioned it works fine . but i need those lines to perform a left outer join

Comment: I don't see how that answers my comment...

Comment: @JhonSkeet No I receive an error in the "model.Where(q => q.ParentId == null).ToList()" It does not successfully display the result. it crashes at the code mentioned above. the error is same as defined in the line of code. Let me know If you have any further question

Comment: Right, so it shows it as a full exception, with a stack trace - *that's* what you should have included, as text, in the question.

Comment: yes, and okay . I will remember that in future :)

Answer (score 0):

The expression, reformatted to make things clearer:

> ```
> Uow.Instance.RepoOf<RoleButtonMatrix>()
>             .GetAll()
>             .Where(q => q.ButtonId == m.Id)
>             .DefaultIfEmpty()
> ```

is used to populate `o`. But 1. that looks like it is returned a single object, and not a collection; 2. it will be null of the collection passed to `DefaultIfEmpty` is empty.

Due to a `from` clause needing a collection you get an error. I expect you can just drop the `DefaultIfEmpty` operator and let LINQ work with an empty collection when there is nothing that matches your criterion.

Comment: Nope I cannot drop the last left outer join if doing so it becomes an inner join and when it becomes inner join . a lot of the value are exclude from the result set. I just want to retain all the previous result set and show me values in the last table (last left outer join) if it may or may not contain a value.

Comment: @KinnanNawaz Please re-read: remove the final operator: let `Enumerable.Join` (or `Queryable.Join`) handle the empty collection.

Comment: @Ricard. can you please a share the changed code snippet.I am not that advance in Linq/Entityframework to figure that out.Thanks in advance

Comment: @KinnanNawaz Just remove the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` (how can I make that simpler?). If you want more start by updating the Q with a complete recreate (not just a fragment); but I'm not going to have time to expend on this anytime soon.

Comment: Removing `.DefaultIfEmpty()` makes it an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN.